# AppImage error: library not found after build

Tags: linux, libreoffice, appimage

(Linux Mint 20)
I'm trying to build an AppImage of LibreOffice Base as a test to see if I can build the individual components of the suite. Here is my `libreoffice-base.yml`:

```
app: LibreOffice_Base

ingredients:
  dist: focal
  packages:
    - libreoffice-base
  sources:
    - deb http://mirror.arizona.edu/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
    - deb http://mirror.arizona.edu/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
  ppas:
    - ppa:libreoffice/ppa

script:
  - cp usr/share/applications/libreoffice-base.desktop .
  - cp usr/share/icons/gnome/256x256/apps/libreoffice-base.png .
```

After I run the command `bash -ex ./pkg2appimage libreoffice-base.yml`, the appimage `out/LibreOffice_Base-.glibc2.29-x86_64.AppImage` is built (no errors in the build process). When I try to run the appimage, I get this error message:

```
$ ./LibreOffice_Base-.glibc2.29-x86_64.AppImage 
/tmp/.mount_LibreOnoGKp7/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/javaldx: error while loading shared libraries: libreglo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
/tmp/.mount_LibreOnoGKp7/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libreglo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Searching for this library, I found that I needed to add the package `uno-libs-private` to the yml file. However, this also results in the aforementioned error message, even though the library `libreglo.so` is right where it's supposed to be (in `LibreOffice_Base/LibreOffice_Base.AppDir/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libreglo.so`. This library is already installed on the system, but that doesn't seem to matter (didn't expect it to). Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?